Read template in parameters list Azure devops yaml
parameters:
  - name: XYZ
    type: object
    default:
      - template: "/Pipelines/Templates/QA/XYZ.yaml"

  - name: ZYX
    type: object
    default:
      - template: "/Pipelines/Templates/QA/ZYX.yaml"

in the templates I have the parameters list like that:
/Pipelines/Templates/QA/XYZ.yaml:


    - projectName: X
      display_name: Y

    - projectName: T
      display_name: R

And it's not reading the content... Is that the right way to implement template content into the parameters list?
I try to insert resources and to write: extended and I read the doc for templates. and no solution..

The template is used to reuse stages, jobs, stages and variables in YAML pipelines. It is not available for parameters in YAML pipelines.

@Nitro5x please check answer below.

In Azure YAML pipelines it's not possible to:

Reuse parameters (e.g. insert template with default or common parameters)
Use templates as the default value of a parameter or variable

You can instead:

Use include templates in order to reuse steps, jobs, stages and variables
Use extends templates to control what is allowed in a pipeline and/or to create a base pipeline.

